# Carousel slide animation doesn't transition as intended Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a problem making my carousel animation work.

I want it to slide-out/slide-in as it does on the Bootstrap website, but in my case it doesn't slide-out, the old item just disappears and slide-in animation occurs.

[I have attached a gif to explain what I mean.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvt7y.gif)

Has anyone else experienced similar issues? Or is my code wrong?

```
<div class="container-fluid b2 pt-5 pb-5">
  <div class="row text-center">
      <h1>
          Why Choose Us
      </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-4 centeralign">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis aspernatur consequuntur maiores sapiente placeat quis dolorem repellendus.</p>
      </div>
  </div>
  
  <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide d-lg-none" data-ride="carousel" data-slide="true">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner pb-5 pt-5">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
          <div class="col-6 padelcarousel">
            <img src="/styles/iconcheck.png" height="75px" width="75px" alt="">
            <h3>Intuitive interface</h2>
            <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea ab hic nisi provident commodi eaque harum ut, distinctio cum. Aut quaerat eveniet asperiores unde dolor modi magni quod iste itaque?</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
          <div class="col-6 padelcarousel">
            <img src="/styles/iconfile.png" height="75px" width="75px" alt="">
            <h3>Performance tracking</h2>
            <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea ab hic nisi provident commodi eaque harum ut, distinctio cum. Aut quaerat eveniet asperiores unde dolor modi magni quod iste itaque?</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
          <div class="col-6 padelcarousel">
            <img src="/styles/iconpuzzle.png" height="75px" width="75px" alt="">
            <h3>High quality content</h2>
            <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea ab hic nisi provident commodi eaque harum ut, distinctio cum. Aut quaerat eveniet asperiores unde dolor modi magni quod iste itaque?</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You Have Use The Bootstrap Starter Template And After I Think Solve This Problem
And Put Your Code After The Body Tag Than Solve This Problem